# Getting a list from a dictionary value

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is created when I deserialise a JSON object based on a class.

For example, my class looks like this

```
public MyClass
{
    public string someString {get;set;}
    public double someDouble {get;set;}
    public bool someBool {get;set;}
    public List<string> valList {get;set;}
    public List<string> valList2 {get;set;}
}
```

When the JSON object is read back in using JSON.NET and deserialised, I end up with my dictionary after a bit of processing.

I can obtain the non-List< string> values easily enough, but can't get the Lists.

I have tried

```
var fi = new List<string>(){};
fi = myDict["myKey"] as List<string>;
```

and

```
fi = myDict["myKey"]
```

but the neither compiles

Is there a way to extract my Lists from the dictionary?

The deserialisation is done simply like this

```
public static T DeserialiseEventData<T>(this T obj, string serialisedData)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialisedData, typeof(T));
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

For the dictionary, I first create the keys (strings) using method 1 which then calls the following method using `vals = GetValuesFromClass(cts);`

```
 private static List<string> GetValuesFromClass<T>(T obj)
    {
        var rv = new List<string>();
        if (obj == null)
            return rv;
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var t = type.GetProperties();
        if (t.Length > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < t.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (t[i].ToString().Contains("List"))
                {
                    var lstProperty = t[i].Name;
                    var res = obj.GetType().GetProperty(lstProperty).GetValue(obj, null) as List<string>;
                    Console.WriteLine(lstProperty);
                    if (res != null)
                    {
                        if (res.Count == 0)
                            rv.AddRange(new List<string>(){ string.Empty });
                        else
                            rv.AddRange(res);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rv.AddRange(new List<string>(){ string.Empty });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var test = t[i].GetValue(obj, null);
                    if (test == null)
                        rv.Add(string.Empty);
                    else
                        rv.Add(test.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

On return, I then do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < translate.Count; ++i)
     rvDict.Add(keys, vals[i]);
```

Comment: can you add a sample of json input (small snippet) and the endpoint method that seralizes it into that class?

Comment: Since you haven't shown neither the json or the dictionary declaration, it is impossible for anyone to answer this question. Nor did you tell us what the compilation error is.

Comment: if you have a `dictionary<string,string>` declared for example you could just convert the dictionary object to a List<T> 
`var fi = YourDictionary.Keys.ToList();`

Comment: I've extended the question which hopefully will help

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that your dictionary is of type `dictionary<string,MyClass>`?

If so, myDict["myKey"] is going to return an instance of MyClass. So if you want the lists, you're going to need to reference them explicitly:

```
fi = myDict["myKey"].valList;
```

By the way, don't initialise fi when you declare it, as the list you create during the declaration will just be garbage collected.

Either:

```
var fi = myDict["myKey"].valList;
```

or

```
List<string> fi;
fi = myDict["myKey"].valList;
```

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I'm spreading this across your posts here and on the Xamarin Developers Facebook group. I'll try to keep the pertinent detail here for reference.

The solution is overly complicated because you're trying to do it all within a general purpose piece of code using Reflection.

Instead, I recommend that you define an interface:

```
public interface IValuesSource
{
    List<string> Values { get; }
}
```

Then, on each of your classes (because you've previously mentioned that they're your classes), implement IValuesSource:

```
public MyClass : IValuesSource
{
    public string someString {get;set;}
    public double someDouble {get;set;}
    public bool someBool {get;set;}
    public List<string> valList {get;set;}
    public List<string> valList2 {get;set;}

    public List<string> Values
    {
        get
        {
            var values = new List<string>();

            values.Add(someString);
            values.Add(someDouble.ToString());
            values.Add(someBool.ToString());
            values.AddRange(valList);
            values.AddRange(valList2);

            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

Each of your deserialized classes will have their own unique implementation of the Values property, but there's no messing about with Reflection, performance will be improved and you have much better encapsulation (for instance, you're not relying on naming conventions for list properties).

Then, as long as you ensure you're referencing the objects via this interface:

```
IValuesSource cts;
  ....
vals = cts.Values;
```